# java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException while calling a stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, exception, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I am calling a stored procedure using spring data jpa

```
 @Query(value = "DECLARE "
        + "p_transaction_header schema.transaction_header_rec \\:= NULL; "
        + "x_voucher_id NUMBER; "
        + "x_return_status VARCHAR2(200); "
        + "x_rejection_reason VARCHAR2(4000); "
        + "BEGIN "
        + "p_transaction_header.source \\:=:source; "
        + "p_transaction_header.total_amount \\:=:totalAmount; "
        + "p_transaction_header.total_records \\:=:totalRecords; "
        + "p_transaction_header.external_key_identifier \\:=:externalKeyIdentifier; "
        + "schema.open_transaction(p_transaction_header, x_voucher_id, x_return_status, x_rejection_reason); "
        + "END", nativeQuery = true)
OpenTransactionBo openTransaction(@Param("source") String source, @Param("totalAmount") BigDecimal totalAmount,
                     @Param("totalRecords") BigDecimal totalRecords, @Param("externalKeyIdentifier") String externalKeyIdentifier);
```

and getting following exception:

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Any idea why this is happening and possible fix for it?